# Missing Debugger tab in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

According to [Googles documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/rundebugconfig) there should be a tab for debugger settings in the Run/Debug configuration but I cannot see it. What can I do to get the debugger options for my project?

I'm using Android Studio 3.2 on mac with lldb install through Android SDK.

[image: Missing Debugger Tab]

Comment: Yes. It seems like it is removed from there(they used the older AS version in the documentation). Are you looking for debugging section when we breakpoint a code and it will appear at the bottom?

Comment: its there for me I am using 3.2 too on windows

Comment: I'm looking for the option to turn on native debugger with lldb

Comment: from sdk manager > sdk tools can you make sure that you have installed lldb.

Comment: did you try setting debuggable flag to true in manifest's application tag?

Comment: @Redman I'm using v3.2 too but I don't see it in there. Are you sure you're using v3.2?

Comment: Even I am using v3.2 @Mohsen on windows and its there for me.

Comment: @Mohsen Yes I am sure of it . My version is 3.2 and its there for me but I don't know how to make it appear and disappear

Comment: Created a ticket, https://partnerissuetracker.corp.google.com/issues/117567915

Comment: @mach I reinstalled the AS and now the tab is there. Weird.

Comment: I have the same issue on both Ubuntu and Windows and there is no way to get it back...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Same bug with Android Studio 2021.3.1 under Linux. I deleted folder `~/.config/Google/AndroidStudio*` to get back the Debugging tab.

Comment: This was working for a while but not anymore...