# cannot find Debugger tab in Edit Configurations (Android Studio Dolphin | 2021.3.1 Patch 1)

Tags: android, android-studio

Today, I suddenly found that I could not find my 'Debugger' tab in 'Edit Configurations', which was normal yesterday.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dERyn.jpg)

Normally, it should look like this, as shown in the figure below, we can add a symbol path to the
'Debugger' tab to debug the program.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gyV7t.png)

I found a similar ticket to this, [No Debugger tab in Edit Configurations (Android Studio 2.3)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42966471/no-debugger-tab-in-edit-configurations-android-studio-2-3), and I had tried what he said, I had uninstalled Android Studio and deleted ~/.android and /Applications/Android\ studio.app fold, I also deleted the ~/.gradle fold, then I reinstalled the Android Studio, but unfortunately, nothing worked.

So can anyone give me some advice? thanks.

Comment: I also tried the method in this link(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52756929/missing-debugger-tab-in-android-studio), but is doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Oh, I found the answer.
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/244807665?pli=1

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WckIT.png)

I don't know when my 'Android NDK Support' got disabled, and I don't know what I did to get it disabled, but anyway, I now turn it on and the 'Debugger' tab is back.